# Displaying percentage of saving price for sale products in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I would like to display the sale savings percentage next to the price.

I use this code in my function.php:

```
// Add save percent next to sale item prices.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $product ) {
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    return $price . sprintf( __(' Save %s', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );
}
```

I have copied this code from a tutorial and it seems to work for everyone else. It also used to work for me but after a new update of WooCommerce, it is not working anymore.

I also deactivated all my CSS files to see if there is maybe a `display:none` and also I have deactivated all my other plugins. Still it does not work.

How can I figure out where the problem is?

Comment: var_dump the variables and see what are their values, plus does the function return an empty value or what ? explain the problem.

Comment: @MehdiBounya even if the return is `return 'Test';`, there is no output. I wouldn't be able to find "Test" anywhere on the product page.

Comment: If you use `return 'True';` you need to `echo` the function for it to appear

Comment: @MehdiBounya well, I could use `echo 'True';` in the function but that wouldn't still display anything. I also tried `var_dump($price . sprintf( __(' Save %s', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' ));`. That gives me nothing. Fact is, nothing in that function runs. Looks like the function is not getting executed.

Comment: ON the linked question/answer you will find the answer.